# Number of likert scale points impact on statistical inferences

Tags: r, statistics, analytics, survey, confidence-interval

I have a survey in which we are debating whether using a 5- or 7-point likert scale for questions around agreement (strongly agree-strongly disagree). The question is whether the 7-point scale would help or hinder the statistical inferences we could make from the data with a sample size of say, 1,800.

One may assume a 7-point likert scale would give you more variability, but at the cost of a wider confidence interval, especially when looking at stratifying by demographic variables.

A back-of-the-envelop calculation of what the confidence interval would be given a random distribution along a 7-point scale and a 5-point scale for a sample size of 1,800 is ~9% and ~6.5% respectively. They both seem high but a 9% CI seems like a high cost for added variability, but I am interested in other's takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts:

The standard 5-category likert scale is typical. If you need a sample size of 1,800 to get a width of ~6.5% for your confidence interval, I'd go with the 5-point scale. That's a lot of people to only get a ~9% width for your CI, which allows you to only estimate which decile your outcome variable is in.